# An outer normal derivative in a PDE problem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> The following problem comes from ch.6 of Evans' book. I have obtained an estimate for the outer (unit) normal derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(x^0)$, but it remains to show
>   $$|Du(x^0)|=\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(x^0)\right|,$$
>   that is, prove that the norm of the gradient vector is equal to the absolute value of the outer normal derivative. A well-known result in calculus reveals that
>   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(x^0)=Du(x^0)\cdot\nu.$$
>   In our case, is it possible to show that the two vectors in the inner product are (anti-)parallel?
>   Please help me finish the last step. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037462/if-a-function-vanishes-on-the-boundary-of-a-domain-its-gradient-on-the-boundary

Comment: The link above may bring something useful to our question.