# Understanding why the gradient of a function $f$ vanishing on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ is parallel to a normal vector to $\partial \Omega$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f$ be defined on $\overline{\Omega}$, where $\partial \Omega$ is smooth, s.t. $f = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and that $f$ differentiable at least on $\partial \Omega$. Then one known result is that the gradient of $f$ at any $p \in \partial \Omega$ is parallel to the normal vector of $\partial \Omega$ at $p$. This post, for example, [If a function vanishes on the boundary of a domain, its gradient on the boundary is a multiple of normal vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1037462/1027258) contains one possible reasoning for this result.

I was wondering that could you also show the result by noticing that the boundary of $\Omega$ forms a level curve $f = 0$ and as the gradient of $f$ is orthogonal to any level curve, it follows that $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to $\partial \Omega$. That is, at $p \in \partial \Omega$,  $\nabla f$ is necessarily a scalar multiple of the normal vector of $\partial \Omega$ at $p$.

Comment: If $\left.f\right|_{\partial\Omega}\equiv 0$, then $\partial\Omega\subset f^{-1}(0)$, but note that $f^{-1}(0)$ need not be a curve (even locally). Indeed, consider the trivial example of $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: @gpr1 Hmm, that is true. So I suppose the the argument for level curves requires that $f$ vanishes only at the boundary of $\Omega$?

Comment: I do not think that this is an efficient way to treat the problem. For instance, if the level sets of $f$ are not connected, then you could suppose that $\partial\Omega$ is a connected component of $f^{-1}(0)$ and the result still holds yet note that you have a strict inclusion $\partial\Omega\subset f^{-1}(0)$.